# C# Grid Cell Formatting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting

Is there any Event in C# Winform for formatting the last Cell or last Row after Complete DataBinding.

Comment: 1) What platform (web or forms) and 2) what do yo mean by "last" - last containg data or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center or System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center.